Drawing rectangle in PNG file
TLDR: My goal is simple. I have a PNG file. I want to draw a rectangle in it using Python and save it to a new file.
I have a PNG file (attached to this post). All I want to do is draw a rectangle in the image using Python and save the image to a new file. Here's code that doesn't work:
import png

org_path = './arragon.png'
altered_path = './altered.png'

f = open(org_path, 'rb')
image = png.Reader(file=f)
width, height, rows, metadata = image.read()

for row in rows:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        row[i] = 255

writer = png.Writer(
    width=width,
    height=height,
    bitdepth=metadata['bitdepth'],
    greyscale=metadata['greyscale'],
    alpha=metadata['alpha']
)

writer.write(open(altered_path, 'wb'), rows)

That last line produces the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/miko/tmp/alter-image/./edit.py", line 23, in <module>
    writer.write(open(altered_path, 'wb'), rows)
File "/home/miko/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/png.py", line 670, in write
    raise ProtocolError(
png.ProtocolError: ProtocolError: rows supplied (0) does not match height (450)

Now, to break it down, I tried just copying the image object to a Writer, without any changes:
import png

f = open(org_path, 'rb')
image = png.Reader(file=f)
width, height, rows, metadata = image.read()

writer = png.Writer(
    width=width,
    height=height,
    bitdepth=metadata['bitdepth'],
    greyscale=metadata['greyscale'],
    alpha=metadata['alpha']
)

writer.write(open(altered_path, 'wb'), rows)

Then I get this message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/miko/tmp/alter-image/./edit.py", line 23, in <module>
    writer.write(open(altered_path, 'wb'), rows)
File "/home/miko/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/png.py", line 668, in write
    nrows = self.write_passes(outfile, check_rows(rows))
File "/home/miko/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/png.py", line 703, in write_passes
    return self.write_packed(outfile, rows)
File "/home/miko/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/png.py", line 738, in write_packed
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
File "/home/miko/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/png.py", line 658, in check_rows
    raise ProtocolError(
png.ProtocolError: ProtocolError: Expected 633 values but got 211 values, in row 0

I can't make heads or tails of what's wrong. Can anybody please tell me how to do this?


What values do you get for width, height, rows, metadata?

width: 211
height: 450
rows: <generator object Reader._iter_bytes_to_values at 0x7fa7f4e45230>
metadata: {'greyscale': False, 'alpha': False, 'planes': 1, 'bitdepth': 8, 'interlace': 0, 'size': (211, 450), 'gamma': 0.45455, 'physical': _Resolution(x=300, y=300, unit_is_meter=False), 'palette': [256 3-value tuples}]}
Sorry about the formatting, I can't figure out how to format in a comment.

Try less. Take out the row in rows editing to begin with, and simplify Writer call too to match a simple example according to purepng code examples (e.g. only parameters width, height, greyscale) and you'll at least have running code. It'll be easier to take baby steps.

Please show your input image and the expected output image - else nobody can help you.

You are reading a paletted image which is 8 bits per pixel.  The Writer object doesn't use that format unless you give it a palette argument.  It's trying to write 24 bits per pixel so a row comes up way short.
Make this subtle change:
writer = png.Writer(
    width=width,
    height=height,
    bitdepth=metadata['bitdepth'],
    greyscale=metadata['greyscale'],
    alpha=metadata['alpha'],
    palette=metadata['palette']
)


I figured it out. It's a bit ham-handed because it changes the value of one of the colors in the palette. However, it does draw a rectangle which is all I really need.
import png

org_path = './arragon.png'
altered_path = './altered.png'

f = open(org_path, 'rb')
image = png.Reader(file=f)
width, height, rows, metadata = image.read()
palette = metadata['palette']

rows = list(rows)

for r in range(len(rows)):
    rows[r] = list(rows[r])

palette[0] = (255, 0, 0)

for r in range(20, 150):
    row = rows[r]

    for i in range(20, 100):
        row[i] = 0

writer = png.Writer(
    width=width,
    height=height,
    bitdepth=metadata['bitdepth'],
    greyscale=metadata['greyscale'],
    alpha=metadata['alpha'],
    palette=metadata['palette']
)

writer.write(open(altered_path, 'wb'), rows)


By changing the palette, you're not just making a color for the rectangle, you're changing one of the colors in your image.  Much better to search the palette and find the color that's already closest to the one you want.  Or better yet convert the image to full RGB, but that's a lot more involved.
